# How to write a structured HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I do not know if I was specf, but actually I want to know if you have any tutorial or some automatic way to do this. See the picture:

[image: http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/html5-2.jpg]

This is the pattern code without width between the lines, or completely along the left side. I wanna look exactly like this:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/HTML_source_code_example.svg/315px-HTML_source_code_example.svg.png]

The lines with banks, margins, ie, fully structured. And I wish to do the same thing with CSS file. How can I do this?

Comment: Pretty much any text editor / IDE that's not Notepad should be able to do this for you. Pick one and learn how to use it. (Look for a feature called "automatic indentation")

Comment: Get a good text editor. As a Microsoft developer, I'd vote for Visual Studio Express (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) but pretty much anything would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to an HTML editor, if you just need something formatted quickly you can use this: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to get a HTML editor. If you want a professional one you can get Dreamweaver but Eclipse, which is free, is almost as good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if there is a way to write code out so it follows standards.
Just download a proper editor, like [e](http://www.e-texteditor.com/), [jedit](http://www.jedit.org/), or [editplus](http://www.editplus.com/)

They tend to indent for you if you just use the tab key.

Programs like dreamweaver might promise good things but deliver anomalies in their actual markup. I bet they've gotten better over the years though.

The best practice is to learn how to program html and css from tutorials. The more experience you have the more natural it will be.